# CRM 2013 Workflow to remove comma from a filed

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have workflow which will automatically generate account number for new records. The account number contains comma [,] for numbers exceeding 1000.

Is it possible with another workflow to update the account number filed and remove the comma? OR can workflow be used to remove certain character or number from a data and leave the rest? The only option I have is to clear the field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible using native functionality. Probably need to build a custom workflow activity to perform this logic.

Comment: Thanks James, can you provide details about the (custom workflow) you are referring to? or any reference link where i can read more about it.

Comment: You will need to write some code, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309745(v=crm.6).aspx